# IE8: text input inside a modal popup doesn't show typed text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, modal-dialog

A very weird scenario:

- I have a popup with one text input and 2 radio inputs
- when I type something in the text input, I can see the cursor moves, but the text is not updated.
- Only when the text input looses focus (e.g. click on a radio button) - I can see the new typed text in the box.
- If this text input has text on page load - I can see the text, but when I try to remove some characters or locate the cursor in the middle of the current text and type some more, I still see the cursor moving and no text changes (until the text input looses focus)

I'm not sure if it is really related to the modal-popup as I have popups where the typing works as expected.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please add a link to your site, or add an example exhibiting the problem on JSFiddle.

Comment: You need to show some relevant code. How can anybody help you if they don't even know which modal you're using?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, but this site requires authentication and this scenario is very complicated to restore in jsfiddle.
I use jquery modal popup.

Comment: @benams: If it's "too complicated scenario" that may be the problem. By making simple example you will see if it work stand-alone or not. Your page may contain collision and by making simple example you may verify if it's problem in jQuery Popup or just your page...

Comment: win XP + IE8  can't display jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Problem with CSS? Maybe focused element have same color for background and text color?

Try this:

```
input:focus { color: black; background: white }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, your suggestion wasn't helpful, I can tell you that if this text input has text on page load - I can see the text, and when I try to remove some characters or locate the cursor in the middle of the current text and type some more, I still see the cursor moving and no text changes (until the window looses focus).